# How can I pass a session value into a Parameter Collection?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to be able to pass in a session value into my parameter collection.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dataApplications" runat="server"
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  SelectMethod="GetSubList"
    TypeName="MApplication">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" DefaultValue="<%= DirectCast(Session("Profile"), PCommon).UserName %>"/>
         ...
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I'm getting this Error Message:

```
Error   158 Literal content ('<asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" DefaultValue="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection'.    C:\TFS\pro\OApp\default.aspx    165
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `asp:sessionparameter` for example:

```
<selectparameters>
    <asp:sessionparameter name="UserName" sessionfield="Profile" type="String" />
</selectparameters>
```

Use the wizard to avoid mistakes.

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm not seeing the wizard for this.  How does it know what session object to use?

Comment: In codebehind you can also do:
dataApplications.SelectParameters["UserName"].DefaultValue = DirectCast(Session("Profile"), PCommon).UserName

Always test the session object for is not Nothing first so you don't access try to access an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Marc also feel free to edit this answer to include additional information.